# UIAlertView not calling

Tags: ios, uialertview

I'm attempting to create a simple webpage browser-esque application, where whenever the user wants to use a back, home, or forward function they are asked through an alert view to confirm.

The console window confirms that it has no problem calling the IBAction but comes up blank whenever I expect it to call Alert View.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
- (IBAction)controlPanelActions:(id)sender{
if (_controlPanel.selectedSegmentIndex == 0)
{
    if ([_viewWeb canGoBack])
    {
        [self askToGoHome:nil];
    }

}



- (IBAction)askToGoHome:(id)sender {
UIAlertView *alertDialog;
alertDialog.tag = 2;
alertDialog = [[UIAlertView alloc]

               initWithTitle: @"Confirm"
               message:@"Continue with Home Action?"
               delegate: self
               cancelButtonTitle: @"Yes"
               otherButtonTitles: @"No", nil];

[alertDialog show];
}





- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView
clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
NSString *buttonTitle=[alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];

if (alertView.tag == 1)
{
    if ([buttonTitle isEqualToString:@"Yes"])
    {
        NSLog(@"back - yes");
        [_viewWeb goBack];
    }
}

 if (alertView.tag == 2)
 {
     NSLog(@"home - pre-yes");
     if ([buttonTitle isEqualToString:@"Yes"])
     {
         NSLog(@"home - yes");
          HOMEPAGEURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:HOMEPAGE];
         [self.viewWeb loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:HOMEPAGEURL]];
     }
 }
if (alertView.tag == 3)
{
    if ([buttonTitle isEqualToString:@"Yes"])
    {
        [_viewWeb goForward];
    }
}
}
```

Comment: For clarification, is the alert blank? Or is it skipped entirely?

Comment: The alert comes up with the options 'Yes' and 'No' as expected. It's only after selecting one of those options that nothing happens.

Comment: `- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title message:(NSString *)message delegate:(id)delegate cancelButtonTitle:(NSString *)cancelButtonTitle otherButtonTitles:(NSString *)otherButtonTitles` I am not seeing a signature for the trailing nil after otherButtonTitles? What is that param?

Comment: I'm unable to find the actual parameter, however without the Nil the auto-complete is telling me "Missing sentinel in method dispatch". And subsequently the program crashed after running through it.

Comment: Thank You for taking the time to look into it. However after moving the 'alertDialog.tag' to the bottom of the IBAction the problem seems to be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You set `alertDialog.tag = 2;`before you call init.

So,everytime you set tag,you set tag to a nil.It will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Alertview alloc and init method sets its tag  to 0.

So `alertDialog.tag = 2;`

will not work.

add this line after alloc and init method.